# How to check the error of a recurrence program?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am reading INTRODUCTION TO ALGORITHMS(Third Edition), There is a maximum subarray problem(P71, chapter 4.1). I change the pseudocode to the real C++ code. Sadly, It has a wrong result. I find I don't know how to find the error of recurrence program.

So I have two quesions: 1.why my code has a wrong result , 2.for this kind of recurrence code , is there a good way to fix the error quicklly?

the pseudocode:

[image]

[image]

my C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits> 
using namespace std;

//find_maximum  used
int mid;
int mleft_sum,mleft_low,mleft_high;  
int mright_sum,mright_low,mright_high;
int mcross_sum,mcross_low,mcross_high;
int result_low,result_high; 

//find_max_crossmid used 
int left_sum,right_sum,sum; 

int A[16] = {13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15,-4,7};

int find_max_crossmid(int a[],int low,int mid, int high, int& max_left, int& max_right)
{
    left_sum = INT_MIN;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = mid; i >= low; i--)
    {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        if (sum > left_sum)
            {
                left_sum = sum;
                max_left = i;   
            }       
    }

    right_sum = INT_MIN;
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = mid + 1; j <= high; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + a[j];
        if (sum > right_sum)
        {
            right_sum = sum;
            max_right = j;
        }
    }
    return (left_sum + right_sum);
}

int find_maximum(int a[],int low, int high)
{
    if (low == high)
    {
        result_low = low;
        result_high = high;
        return a[low];
    }   
    else 
    {
        mid = (low + high)/2;

        mleft_sum = find_maximum(a,low,mid);

        mright_sum = find_maximum(a,mid + 1,high);

        mcross_sum = find_max_crossmid(a,low,mid,high,mcross_low,mcross_high);
        if ((mleft_sum >= mright_sum) && (mleft_sum >= mcross_sum))
        {
            result_low = mleft_low; result_high = mleft_high;
             return mleft_sum;  
        }
        else if ((mright_sum >= mleft_sum) && (mright_sum >= mcross_sum))
        {
            result_low = mright_low; result_high = mright_high;
            return mright_sum;
        }
        else{
            result_low = mcross_low; result_high = mcross_high;
            return mcross_sum;
        }   
    }
}

int main()
{   
    cout << find_maximum(A,0,15);
    return 0;
}
```

the result should be 43,but I got 34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took very long for me to find the bug. Thought in different perspective.

Then issue is mid value.

**keep it as local variable.**

```
int mid = (low+high)/2;
```

when you look at printing some values in loop, you can find it.

```
cout<<low<<"; "<<mid<<"; "<<high<<": ";
cout<<mleft_sum<<"; "<<mright_sum<<"; "<<mcross_sum<<endl;
```

Actual Iteration should be like this:

```
0; 0; 1: 13; -3; 10
2; 2; 3: -25; 20; -5
0; 1; 3: -25; 20; 5
4; 4; 5: -3; -16; -19
6; 6; 7: -23; 18; -5
4; 5; 7: -23; 18; -21
0; 3; 7: -23; 18; 17
8; 8; 9: 20; -7; 13
10; 10; 11: 12; -5; 7
8; 9; 11: 12; 12; 25
12; 12; 13: -22; 15; -7
14; 14; 15: -4; 7; 3
12; 13; 15: -4; 7; 18
8; 11; 15: -4; 18; 16
0; 7; 15: -4; 18; 43
43[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Your program iterated like this:

```
0; 0; 1: 13; -3; 10
1; 1; 2: -3; -25; -28
2; 2; 3: -25; 20; -5
1; 2; 3: -25; 20; -5
0; 2; 3: -25; 20; 5
3; 3; 4: 20; -3; 17
4; 4; 5: -3; -16; -19
3; 4; 5: -3; -3; 1
5; 5; 6: -16; -23; -39
6; 6; 7: -23; 18; -5
5; 6; 7: -23; 18; -5
3; 6; 7: -23; 18; -4
0; 6; 7: -23; 18; -4
7; 7; 8: 18; 20; 38
8; 8; 9: 20; -7; 13
7; 8; 9: 20; 20; 31
9; 9; 10: -7; 12; 5
10; 10; 11: 12; -5; 7
9; 10; 11: 12; 12; 7
7; 10; 11: 12; 12; 38
11; 11; 12: -5; -22; -27
12; 12; 13: -22; 15; -7
11; 12; 13: -22; 15; -7
13; 13; 14: 15; -4; 11
14; 14; 15: -4; 7; 3
13; 14; 15: -4; 7; 18
11; 14; 15: -4; 18; 18
7; 14; 15: -4; 18; 34
0; 14; 15: -4; 34; 34
34[Finished in 0.5s]
```